# Obj C: Checking against an integer in NSUserDefaults

Tags: ios, xcode, if-statement

Here's my situation - lets see if any coding geniuses out there can help me out!

My situation is thus:

I have an integer stored in NSUserDefaults by the name of @"scifi1" - it could be one of....say 250+ values - non sequential, but all known (i.e. it's from multiple choice)

I need to check the value of said integer and dependent on what it is perform a different action.

Now, my code as it stands is thus

```
if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"scifi1"] == 040){
            [self spaceup];
        }
        if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"scifi1"] == 10040){
            [self spaceup];
            [self ctrlup];
        }
        if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"scifi1"] == 20040){
            [self spaceup];
            [self altup];
        }
```

And while this works, once you've added in dozens more the code becomes 
a) Very long
b) When done for several different methods, too long for the iPhone to reasonably handle, and in fact Xcode throws out a GCC 4.2 error telling me so.

So what's the best way to check this out? there must be a better way then repeated 'if' statements.

I tried setting up a switch/case style setup but as the integers aren't constants it seemed unhappy with this - and to be honest, I'm not sure having switch/cases are any better in the long run for me than having multiple if statements.

Anyone got any sharp ideas?

Edit:

Ok I've tried this as an experiment.

```
-(void)checkandrunup { 
    if (tempInt == 040){
        [self spaceup];
    }
    if (tempInt == 10040){
        [self spaceup];
        [self ctrlup];
    }
    if (tempInt == 20040){
        [self spaceup];
        [self altup];
    }
    if (tempInt == 30040){
        [self spaceup];
        [self shiftup];
    }}


-(IBAction)torpup{
    //If to check for edit and display popover
    if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"viewEdit"] == YES) {

    }
    else {
        NSInteger tempInt = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"scifi1"];




    }
        //First Sound
        if([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"viewHidden"] == YES) {
            NSString *path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",
                              [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath],
                              @"/beep1.WAV"];
            SystemSoundID soundID;
            NSURL *filePath = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path isDirectory:NO];
            AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((CFURLRef)filePath, &soundID);
            AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID);  }
        //Second Sound
        else {
            NSString *path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",
                              [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath],
                              @"/beep2.WAV"];
            SystemSoundID soundID;
            NSURL *filePath = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path isDirectory:NO];
            AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((CFURLRef)filePath, &soundID);
            AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID);
        }
    }
```

However the tempInt doesn't pass through from Torpup to checkandrunup - is there a way to get this to happen?

Comment: I haven't got that far as to be able to get the exact quote, but I know it'll not be happy about the number of if's it's checking. If as per your answer I use else if I wonder if that'll keep it happier...shall try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was about to say "use a switch", but you say the values aren't constant. In this case, I'd suggest:

1. Store the integer in a value and use that for comparison instead of calling `standardUserDefaults` and `integerForKey:` a thousand times.
2. Use `else if` in between your checks. As you have it right now, if the first check succeeds all other checks are still done even though you don't need to execute them.
3. If possible, try to map the values to constants first and then use a switch or if you have some constant values, check those with a switch first.
4. If the method is becoming too big, you might split it up into several methods, each checking a group of options Maybe there's a condition you can check to know which method to cell then, like `if (value >= 1000 && value < 2000)`. If not, make sure to have a return value that tells whether additional checks need to be done.

Comment: I just tried something a little different - any chance yo can take a look at the edit I'm about to throw up.

Comment: How about you add an argument to your method, like `-(void)checkandrunup:(NSInteger)tempInt` ;-)

Comment: So would that pull the same tempint as in the torpup method? (Kinda finding my feet here still lol)

Comment: @David26th: Not automatically, of course you would also need to call it that way: `[self checkandrunup:myOtherTempInt];` or `[self checkandrunup:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"scifi1"]];`

Comment: The second option won't work - essentially each time a method runs I have it store the value for it's "Scifi1" (or 2,3,4,5 whatever) into tempInt - my hope was to pass it to a seperate method to cut down on repeat coding.